# Sentence generation from Keywords.Each keyword have bag of related words

Tags: python, nlp, nlg

I am working on Natural Language Generation project. Now I have bags of keywords and I am trying to generate sentence of pattern Subject+verb+object. Is there any tool or package or library to get sentences when i give bag of subject,bag of verb and bag of object?
Example:
    subject=[teacher,student]
    verb=[teach]
    object=[book]
    answer: teacher teaching student from books.

Comment: Train a language model on large collection of english text. Then create a list of candidates by going through permutations of words you are given. Use your language model to assign each candidate a probability. Most probably the likeliest candidate is also a correct english sentence...

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Assuming the words in your bag of words are tagged with word categories such as verb or noun, you could use a realiser such as [SimpleNLG](https://github.com/simplenlg/simplenlg).

Effectively you would write a bunch of sentence specification templates and a script to look into your bag of words and use your templates.

For example, for your sentence "teacher teaching students from books" you could have the following sentence specification template:

- Subject = a noun, e.g. teacher
- Verb = a verb, e.g. teach (form = present participle)
- Object = a noun, e.g. student (number = plural)
- Postmodifier = { preposition = from , noun = books (number = plural) }

Note this approach will give you morphologically and syntacticly valid sentences, even though some may sound funny such as "books teaching teachers from students".